# Why is the size of audio sample in mdat atom of mp4 file more than 300 bytes?

Tags: android, audio, byte, mp4, aac

I have a **mp4** file. When I work with its `mdat` atom, I see that audio data is stored in the samples. **The size of each sample is more than 300 bytes (usually around 370 bytes) and less than 600 bytes.**

I wonder why?
Maybe it's a stupid question. But cannot find the answer. Please help me!
The audio parameters of my mp4 file: 44100 Hz, bitrate: 128000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are trying to find out why the encoded AAC frame size is around 370?

Sampling rate = 44100 [pcm samples/sec]
Decoded AAC frame size = 1024 [pcm samples/frame]
Bitrate = 128000 [bits/sec]

therefore ([bits/sec]/[samples/sec]*[sample/frame]=[bits/frame])

1 AAC frame = 371 [bytes/frame]

Actual frame sizes differ (AAC specification is not strict, this depends on encoder implementation),  but on average they should be 371 in order to target the 128000 bitrate.

Answer (score 4):

Just a confusion of terminology. In video, "sample" and "frame" are interchangeable. In audio they are not. So 300 bytes is actually a full frame of audio. Every audio codec has a different frame size. AAC for examples has 1024 samples per frame.

Comment: I wonder why the "frame size" is more than 300 bytes and less than 600 bytes.

Comment: Is it PCM audio, or compressed?  Do the sample timestamps match what you expect?

Comment: I can watch the video normally. No problem. I don't know its PCM or compressed. I create a MP4 video with H264 video and AAC audio. The raw data of audio is stored in mdat atom. And I see that it is stored in the samples (or frames as you said) with size > 300 bytes.

Comment: AAC is compressed. More complex signals require more bits to encode.

Comment: Is there any way to explain why the sample (or frame) size is in the interval 300-600 bytes?

Comment: At what level of understanding? It seem this does not match you expectation, but I'm unsure what your expectation is. At the lowest level, this is an information theory problem. Look into Claude Shannon's work.